# Strong signal (of Internet)

Tags: adjectives

Do we say 'the signal (Internet) is not strong enough to stream a video'?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Signal" is usually reserved for cable, satellite, radio, or cellular connections, and is used in reference to the signal needed to watch cable or satellite TV, listen to the radio, or carry on a telephone conversation.

The "connection," the "internet connection," or, simply, the "internet" would suffice for your purposes. These are the most common terms I've heard used colloquially. Oftentimes, these terms are used with a possessive pronoun, such as "my,""his,""her", or "their," rather than the definite article "the." This is especially common when referring to the Internet connection speed at a person's home, or the connection speed of the Internet service that the person pays for, and in these cases the possessive pronoun usually refers to the host or payee in question: "I tried to do my research paper at the Johnson's house, but **their internet** is too slow."

If a person is on-the-go and using cellular data, the default is generally to use the first person possessive.

"I can't FaceTime right now, **my** internet is too slow"

If the internet connection is public, i.e. Starbucks, xfinitywifi, etc., or if you are in a place where a lot of people are using the connection, it is more common to hear the definite article used.

"I'll have to go somewhere else to watch this; I'm at Starbucks but **the** internet is too slow."

This is a situation where "their" could have been used, so sometimes it depends on context and who you may be speaking to. The definite article "the" is also often used if the internet connection in question is one often used by the same people in the same place, i.e. members of the same household or coworkers in an office building.

To understand this, imagine a hypothetical scenario wherein two coworkers in the same office are trying to exchange a document over email:

Jimmy: "You didn't receive my email? I guess I'll try again; I tried to send it earlier but **the connection** was too slow."

Ryan: "Really? That's weird, **my internet** is working fine."

There are a few things to note here:

1. Jimmy says "the" because the internet "belongs" to both of them, and says the "connection" instead of internet. This is not a rule, but oftentimes "connection" will be used if the internet user is attempting to make an internet communication, such as an e-mail, video call, or text message.
2. Ryan says "my" because there is a difference in their respective connection speeds, therefore "my" is appropriate to differentiate the different qualities of internet connection to which they are referring. He also uses "internet" instead of connection. This is also not a rule, but "internet" is commonly used when the connection in question is being used for self-serving needs, such as streaming video, downloading music, or surfing the web. In this case, "internet" is used because Ryan is evaluating the quality of his connection *not* based on its ability to communicate with Jimmy, but simply as an overall evaluation of its ability to serve *his own* internet needs.

Hope this helps.

EDIT

Adjectives used in reference to the connection are usually "fast" or "slow," rather than "strong" or "weak."

Answer (score 1):

'the connection' or 'the packet speed' in reference to the speed and ability of transfer and upload/download , dependent on file size

Comment: "The Internet connection" is a fairly standard phrase, but not "packet speed." You would be more likely to see something like "there is not enough bandwidth to stream video."

Comment: I wouldn't personally, as i prefer not to be incorrect with my wordings or advise/information.  Otherwise i would not see a point to this question. We are not connected to the internet. We are connected to routers>->servers, on the initial grid and optic providers.  The packet speed is the determination of what processes and the rate of, that we can achieve/obtain. If we were connected to 'the internet', then  i assure you, we would have NO issues or even the conversing about 'connection'.   SOURCE -- open grid script and source code editor for VR and cross grid ability. EST. 2003